# Deslogar ao fechar aplicativo

Tags: android

Galera, tenho um app que executa login, para isso eu utilizo `sharedPreferences()`, Tenho um botão de sair que faz com que o usuário deslogue do sistema, que funciona desta forma:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("info",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
Log.d("ESTADO_APP", "Deslogado");
finish();
```

E funciona perfeitamente, eu gostaria de quando eu fechar o App ele deslogasse, mas não quando minimizar e deixar aberto em segundo plano, só quando ele realmente for finalizado.

Comment: Tentasse colocar tua lógica de logout no ondestroy? Se não funcionar tem essa resposta aqui que sugere tu criar um serviço pra notificar quando tuas tasks forem destruídas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744933/android-ondestroy-isnt-called-when-i-close-the-app-from-the-recent-apps-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tinha recomendado que você poderia usar o método `onDestroy`, que é chamado quando o sistema precisa de memória ou quando o método finish() é chamado. Mas isto poderia não funcionar em alguns casos. Então, o melhor a ser feito é: você não precisa limpar os dados quando o usuário sair do app, mas sim quando ele entrar.

Para isto, a gente faz uma `SplashActivity` ou uma classe `Application`. Você pode escolher qualquer uma.

> SplahActivity

A gente não vai usar nenhum layout em nossa SplashActivity porque não é preciso. Não queremos que o usuário perca muito tempo nela, vai ser algo rápido, só iremos mostrar o ícone do app e pronto.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

Nesta tag de estilo, foque no atributo **windowBackground**, pois ele é quem irá posicionar o ícone do nosso aplicativo na SplashScreen. Você pode trocar por uma Drawable também, se caso desejar fazer uma imagem personalizada ou deixar sem nenhuma imagem de background.

Não esqueça de definir essa classe no **Manifest** como o **Entrypoint** da aplicação.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle cycle) {
        super.onCreate(cycle);
        clearData();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private void clearData() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("info",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}


<activity
        android:name="br.com.exemplo.SplashActivity" <!-- muda para o endereço correto -->
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> Application

Você só vai precisar criar uma classe que herda de Application e depois limpar os dados.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       clearData();
       startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
       finish();
    }

    private void clearData() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("info",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Não esqueça de apontar no Manifest na tag Application o nome para a sua classe MyApp.

```
<Application
 .....
    android:name=".package.MyApp" />
```

Como foi dito, no método onDestroy fica um tanto quanto ruim de colocar porque nem sempre ele é **chamado**.

Comment: Onde eu crio a tag de estilo? na pasta de Layout?

Comment: Opa, desculpe-me por não lhe informar isto. Você pode copiar e colar o código `style` no arquivo `styles.xml` que fica em `res/values`

Comment: Brenddon, editei a resposta e adicionei mais detalhes.

Comment: Valeu cara, com a SplahActivity, se eu apertar o botão de voltar na activity depois do login ele não fecha o app porém chama a splash aí desloga, e com a aplication funciona normal, só que ao logar e apertar o botão de voltar logo em seguida ele volta  pra página de login. Meu app funciona assim Splash > Login > Principal

Comment: Eu entendi o porque, Quando eu uso a Application, o Entrypoint  fica na Main(Página de login), aí ela abre duas vezes, porque eu  chamo ela também na MyApp, e o  Entrypoint   é obrigatório ter em alguma Activity, aí eu resolvi redirecionando pra activity depois do login e fazendo o tratamento dos SharedPreferences lá, você  ajudou mto man!

Comment: @BrenddonAnjos, o EntryPoint deve ficar na SplashActivity mesmo, porque aí tu já manda ele pra tela de Login ou para a Main. Mas o entrypoint do aplicativo (launcher e tals) deve ser na própria SplashActivity.

Comment: Eu digo isso porque ela é uma activity mais leve, não tem nenhum layout e vai carregar muito mais rápido que as outras. Ela apenas vai direcionar o usuário para a próxima tela. Tu pode fechar ela com "finish()".