# Iniciar um app com uma tela que não é a Main?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, app

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível iniciar um aplicativo com uma activity que não é a activity principal, e a partir dela chamar a principal, como uma espécie de login pra acessar o menu principal, ou ainda uma confirmação para continuar. Se sim, como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer essa mudança é necessário alterar seu `manifest.xml`

Ex:

```
<!-- Login -->
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Após fazer isso, basta remover todo o código `<intent-filter>...</intent-filter>` do nó da `.MainActivity`.

É necessário apenas uma `activity` possua essa instrução.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu já expliquei nessa minha resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269342/deslogar-ao-fechar-aplicativo/269349#269349), é recomendado que você utilize um `SplashScreen` para tal.

Eu vou tentar te explicar, de maneira simples, como essa estrutura deve funcionar, principalmente em um sistema com `Login` e com uma `Dashboard`.

A Activity `SplashActivity` só ficará responsável por verificar se existe algum usuário logado, e você pode fazer isto com [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br).

Se tem um usuário conectado, a Activity vai abrir a tela `Dashboard`, senão, a tela de `Login`.

Você também pode salvar **tokens** do usuário para lembrar quem é que está conectado ou até mesmo a **ID** dele, se caso for um **sistema** mais simples.

> SplashActivity

Essa tela não tem, e não deve, ter nenhum layout pra não deixar ela mais pesada. Apenas colocaremos coisas mais essenciais, que são a lógica de negócio para levar o usuário para outra página.

Você deve definir um tema abaixo e usar um background na tela para não deixá-la tão feia. O background pode ser uma imagem criada por você, e você pode colocá-la na pasta `res\drawable` ou pode ser o próprio ícone do teu aplicativo que fica em `res\mipmap` .

O código abaixo deve ficar em `res\values\styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

Ele vai estilizar a tela para não deixá-la tão feia. Você pode modificá-lo normalmente. Para mudar o ícone da tela, modifique o atributo `windowBackground`.

Já o código abaixo é a lógica padrão da sua Splash, é ela quem ficará responsável por realizar o controle de usuários.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        pref = getSharedPreferences("user_info",MODE_PRIVATE);
        isUserLogged = pref.getBoolean("user_logged", false);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, isUserLogged ? DashboardActivity.class : LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

E então, para fazer tudo isto funcionar normalmente, você só deve definir a **SplashActivity** como tela de **Launcher** no **AndroidManifest**.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Esse tipo de método é mais recomendado porque tu não vai fazer o usuário esperar pra ele poder acessar teu app. Digo, algumas pessoas usam `Timers` em SplashActivity e fazem o usuário esperar 2 ou 5 segundos para exibirem o app. Com isso, o app apenas verifica o que foi informado e abre. Bem simples e mais rápido pro usuário.